# How to use BIC and AIC score for Lasso-GridSearchCV in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want use AIC & BIC to select the parameter alpha for lasso. However sklearn only has `LassoLarsIC` to do this which does not accept sparse matrix and thus does not fit my case. As a result I decide to use `GridSearchCV` and create a customized scorer. Below is my try:

```py
def bic_error_func(y_true, y_pred, coefs):
    n_samples = len(y_true)
    mse = np.average((y_true - y_pred) ** 2, axis=0)
    sigma2 = np.var(y_true)
    eps64 = np.finfo("float64").eps
    K = log(n_samples)
    mask = np.abs(coefs) > np.finfo(coefs.dtype).eps
    df = np.sum(mask)
    
    score = (n_samples * mse / (sigma2 + eps64) + K * df)
    return score

from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
bic_scorer = make_scorer(bic_error_func, greater_is_better=False)
```

However, unlike the example in [Defining your scoring strategy from metric functions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-metric-functions), I need the additional argument `coefs` to calculate this score. How can I make the wrapped scoring function work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `make_scorer` (and the expected form of a scoring method for a grid search) is a callable with signature `estimator, X, y`; you should skip `make_scorer` and define such a callable directly.  Then you can use the estimator's fitted attribute `coefs_` directly.  (The `greater_is_better=False` option of `make_scorer` just negates the score, so you should probably define this alternate custom scorer as *negative* BIC.)

Note however that in a `GridSearchCV`, you'll always be computing the score on the test folds, which deviates from the intention behind BIC.

Comment: If using `GridSearchCV` is wrong, what should I do? Can I simply set `cv=1`?

Comment: I find I cannot set `cv=1`. So should I manually run a grid search for different α on the whole data?

Comment: That's probably the cleanest approach.  If you really want to have the benefits of `GridSearchCV` without copying large parts of it, I drafted a hack in [this answer at DS.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66238/55122) to set aside a single row as the "test set" that won't get used.  By setting `return_train_score=True` and using a custom `refit` callable, you could get the optimal BIC on the training set (possibly aside the one row, or maybe you can think of a better hack).

Comment: I suppose you could still do a k-fold split, but just ignore the test scores (don't use the default `refit`) and use the training scores that would be real BIC's.

Comment: Thanks for your hack method. Btw, if I do a `cv=2` and select by the average bic, how and to what extent would this hurt the intention behind BIC in theory?

Comment: I'm not sure.  The sample size decreasing would seem to be the largest change in the actual scores, but since you're just comparing them across different regularization strengths, that might not be a big deal.