# How can I implement score weights on my GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm running a `RandomizedSearchCV` on a dataset with a time-component. I wish to predict `n` periods ahead, but I would like to give more weight to the scoring function for periods in the nearby future than in the later future. In other words, my model performance should be evaluated against some score weights, where the weight on the first periods is higher than in later periods. See my code below (my real life case is a lot more complex with more parameters to estimate than this, but this captures the idea of what I'd like to accomplish):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from scipy.stats import randint
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, TimeSeriesSplit

X = np.random.normal(size=(1000, 20))
y = np.random.normal(size=1000)
score_weights = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('rf', None)])

param_grid_ex = [{
   "rf": [RandomForestRegressor()],
   "rf__max_depth": randint(low=1, high=100)
}]

# Forecast two weeks (14 periods) ahead on 5 folds
timeseries_split = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=14)

# Specify the gridsearch
search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipe,
                            param_distributions=param_grid_ex,
                            n_iter=10,
                            cv=timeseries_split,
                            refit=True)

search.fit(X=X, y=y)
```

I have tried several things (specifying `fit_params`, `score_params`, passing my own scorer function generated by `make_scorer`), yet none seem to work. Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: According to [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html). You can pass your function (callable) in `scoring` parameter

Comment: If you use a callable `scoring`, you probably don't want to use `make_scorer`.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69454210/10495893